# How can I check if filename contains a portion of a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, filenames

I have a userform in 2008 vb express edition. A part number is created from user input via a concat string. I want to then check if a certain portion of the part number exists in the existing file names in a directory. Below is a more detailed explanation.

This is my code for creating a part number from the user input on the form.

```
L_PartNo.Text = String.Concat(CB_Type.Text, CB_Face.Text, "(", T_Width.Text, "x", T_Height.Text, ")", mount, T_Qty.Text, weep, serv)
```

I then have the following code to tell the user if the configuration (part no) they just created exists

```
L_Found.Visible = True
If File.Exists("Z:\Cut Sheets\TCS Products\BLANK OUT SIGN\" & (L_PartNo.Text) & ".pdf") Then
        L_Found.Text = "This configuration exists"
      Else
        L_Found.Text = "This configuration does NOT exist"
      End If
```

This is where I need help. The part no will look like this BX002(30x30)A1SS I want to compare 002(30x30) (just this part of the file name) to all the files in one directory. I want a yes or no answer to the existance and not a list of all matching files. The code below is everything I've tried, not all at the same time.

```
Dim b As Boolean
b = L_PartNo.Text.Contains(NewFace)

Dim NewFace As String = String.Concat(CB_Face.Text, "(", T_Width.Text, "x", T_Height.Text, ")")
Dim NewFace = L_PartNo.Text.Substring(2, 10)

If filename.Contains(NewFace) Then
        lNewFace.Visible = False
      Else
        lNewFace.Visible = True
      End If
```

The code below was a translation from the answer in C# but it does not work either

```
Dim contains As Boolean = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any(Function(f) [String].Equals(f, "myfilethree", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do it without the fancy LINQ and Lambda which seem to be confusing you:

```
Public Function FileMatches(folderPath As String, filePattern As String, phrase As String) As Boolean
    For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, filePattern)
        If fileName.Contains(phrase) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Or, if you need it to be case insensitive:

```
Public Function FileMatches(folderPath As String, filePattern As String, phrase As String) As Boolean
    For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, filePattern)
        If fileName.ToLower().Contains(phrase.ToLower()) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

You would call the method like this:

```
lNewFace.Visible = FileMatches(path, "*.pdf", NewFace)
```

Comment: I get the following error "EnumerateFiles is not a member of System.IO.Directory". I googled this and found that this does not work with visual basic 2008 express edition net framework 3.5. Is this right? Can I upgrade to net framework 4.0?

Comment: @UBel I updated the example to show how you can do the same thing without the newer versions of the framework.

Comment: I did some modifying and added an exit for, this worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 lNewFace.Visible = IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf").Where(Function(file) file. _
            Substring(2, 10) = NewFace).FirstOrDefault Is Nothing
```

Consider that the substring function will throw an exception if its arguments exceed the length of the string it is parsing

Comment: This makes lNewFace visible under any condition match or not. Some of the code I tried before would create the same affect. I don't understand the coding well enough to modify. I replacecd path with the path to the files. do I need to change something else? Maybe in "Where(Function(file) file" and what does "FirstOrDefault Is Nothing" mean? I'll google in the meanwhile.

Comment: It means "first result returned or Nothing"; in short, the statement on the right side of the equals will return true if no match is found. Hard to believe it's (incorrectly) always making the label visible regardless of the value of NewFace.  Set some breakpoints and check the values of the variables (path, NewFace, etc.) - are you sure the resulting filepath exists?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tweaked the code from SteveDog and got what I needed. Thanks again.