# Vbscript to figure out if file(s) in a folder contain certain characters and check the modified date on them

Tags: vbscript

I am having trouble getting this to work. I keep getting the following error "Expecting then line 23" The error is somewhere where the first If File.Name Contains section.

I know it is probably something rather simple that I am missing but for the life of me cant see it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
reportDate = date
dtMonth = Month(reportDate)
If dtMonth < 10 Then
    dtMonth = "0" & dtMonth
End If
dtDay = Day(reportDate)
If dtDay < 10 Then
    dtDay = "0" & dtMonth
End If
dtYear = Year(reportDate)
saveFormatDate = dtYear & dtMonth & dtDay

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set recentFile = Nothing
Set goodFile = 0
Set badFile = 0
Set goodFileName = "To_Vendor_" & saveFormatDate

For Each file in fso.GetFolder("C:\Data_Files").Files

    If file.Name contains(goodFileName) Then
        recentDate = File.DateLastModified
        If recentDate > DateAdd("H",-6,Now) Then
            goodFile = goodFile + 1         
        Else
            badFile = badFile + 1           
        End If
    Else
        ' Do nothing
    End If
Next

If badFile > 0 Then
    wscript.echo "No files created within the last 6 months"
Else
    If goodFile > 0 Then
        'execute batch file eventually to initiate SFTP process
        'not adding this until working
        wscript.echo "Files are going to be sent."
    Else
        wscript.echo "No good files to be sent."
    End if
End If

wscript.quit
```

Comment: Why do you use the `vb.net` tag? The 'function' `contains` does not exist in VBScript, and _no_ function would work the way you have written it. Use `instr`.

Comment: I am trying to write this in vbscript and I could have sworn I found several other links on this site that use contains with vbscript

Comment: Referenceing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229874/how-can-i-check-if-filename-contains-a-portion-of-a-string-in-vb-net

Comment: Not sure if contains is a valid function, but if it is, you're missing a dot between file.Name and contains.

Comment: I am an very new to all this and contains probably isnt a valid option. I ended up using left and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues...

1. You probably didn't mean this:

   ```
   dtDay = "0" & dtMonth
   ```

   I'm assuming you meant this instead?

   ```
   dtDay = "0" & dtDay
   ```

   BTW, here's a one-liner to pad things like this:

   ```
   dtDay = Right("0" & Day(reportDate), 2)
   ```
2. You shouldn't use 'Set' with general variables. Remove it from these lines:

   ```
   Set recentFile = Nothing ' This isn't being used at all
   Set goodFile = 0
   Set badFile = 0
   Set goodFileName = "To_Vendor_" & saveFormatDate
   ```
3. Change this:

   ```
   If file.Name contains(goodFileName) Then
   ```

   To:

   ```
   If InStr(file.Name, goodFileName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
   ```